# Codeigniter not working in subfolder of root wordpress website

Tags: php, codeigniter

I upload the codeigniter in the subfolder and in the root I have a wordpress webstie. I change the config base url with the name of subfolder name like this

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/onlinebooks/';
```

But after this still getting 404 for any controller I call on url

Can Anybody help me regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Create a .HtaAccess in root folder and paste this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On


  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>


   ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

404, maybe you have modified your code to remove the `index.php` on the url, this would be the correct `.htaccess`.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /onlinebooks/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|stylesheets|javascript)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```